# MySQL: how to include '\G' inside a procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

I am creating a procedure in MySQL with the following codes:

```
delimiter #
drop procedure if exists a03_strings #
create procedure a03_strings ()
begin
  select concat(cl_id, ' ',cl_name_last, ', ', cl_name_first) as Client
  , group_concat(coalesce(concat(an_name, ' (', an_type, ')'), 'no animals')) as Animals
  from vt_clients
  left join vt_animals using (cl_id)
  group by cl_id\G;
end;
#
```

I added `\G` at line 9 in order to get the following output:

[image]
So the output is not a table but rows.

When I test this just as select statements it worked with `\G`. However, when I include `\G` inside the procedure and it is giving me error saying that I cannot include a procedure inside another procedure.

Is there an alternative to achieve the output I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no: '\G' is handled by the mysql client not the DBMS (where the stored procedure runs. But you can simply:

```
mysql> create procedure a03_strings ()
    -> begin
    -> select concat(cl_id, ' ',cl_name_last, ', ', cl_name_first) as Client
    -> , group_concat(coalesce(concat(an_name, ' (', an_type, ')'), 'no animals')) as Animals
    -> from vt_clients
    -> left join vt_animals using (cl_id)
    -> group by cl_id\G;
    -> end;
    -> #
 ...
 mysql-> call a03strings() \G#
```

Or use this as your SELECT...

```
SELECT IF (rowselect='A', 
   CONCAT('Client: ', ilv.Client), 
   CONCAT('Animals', ilv.Animals)
FROM (
    select concat(cl_id, ' ',cl_name_last, ', ', cl_name_first) as Client
    , group_concat(coalesce(concat(an_name, ' (', an_type, ')'), 'no animals')) as Animals
    from vt_clients
    left join vt_animals using (cl_id)
    group by cl_id
) ilv,
(SELECT 'A' AS rowselect UNION SELECT 'B') AS rowmultiplier
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up using `select concat('Client :', concat(cl_id, ' ',cl_name_last, ', ', cl_name_first), '\n Animals: ', group_concat(coalesce(concat(an_name, ' (', an_type, ')'), 'no animals')))`